# Finding combinations that do not exist in a given data set

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

Let us say I have a binary data set and I want to find out which combinations still did not occur. 
For example:

```
X1 X2 X3
1  0  1
0  1  1
```

As one can see the combination `X1=1`, `X2=1` and `X3=0` did not happen. The order does not matter. Is there any package that can do this or is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all possible binary permutation and then make an anti-join with your data seems to be the easiest way.

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

test <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,0), V2 = c(0,1), V3 = c(1,1))

all_perm <- data.frame(permutations(n = 2, r = 3, v = c(0,1), repeats.allowed = TRUE))
colnames(all_perm) <- colnames(test)

anti_join(all_perm, test)
```

Comment: I have 9 columns and 85 observations. Should I put `n = 2` and `r = 9`?

Comment: Yes. r is the size of the source vector v, here v = c(0,1). r is the size of the target, here it's the number of variable so 9.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setdiff` as shown.  No packages are used.

```
DF <- data.frame(X1 = 1:0, X2 = 0:1, X3 = c(1L, 1L)) # test input

g <- do.call("expand.grid", rep(list(0:1), ncol(DF)))
names(g) <- names(DF)

setdiff(g, DF)
```

giving:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  0  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  1  0
4  1  1  0
5  0  0  1
6  1  1  1
```

if the intention was that every row of DF has the same number of 1's and we should only include rows with that number of 1's then use `combn` like this. Again, no packages are used.

```
nc <- ncol(DF)
k <- sum(DF[1, ])  # no of 1's in each row of DF

g <- t(combn(nc, k, function(x) +(seq(nc) %in% x)))
g <- as.data.frame(g)

# now repeat the last two lines of the prior approach like this:
names(g) <- names(DF)
setdiff(g, DF)
```

giving:

```
X1 X2 X3 
 1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

An efficient solution that should scale rather well (at least better than approaches that create all permutations), would be to work with the positions of 1 values.

```
#the data
m <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    1
#[2,]    0    1    1

#number of 1 per row
n <- 2

#find positions of 1s
library(Matrix)
M <- Matrix(t(m), sparse = TRUE)
inds <- matrix(M@i + 1L, n, byrow = TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    3


#all possible positions
combs <- combn(seq_len(ncol(m)), n, simplify = FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 2 3

#missing combs
setdiff(combs, asplit(inds, 1))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

sparseMatrix(j = unlist(mis), 
             i = rep(seq_along(mis), each = n), 
             dims = c(length(mis), ncol(m)))
#1 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"
#
#[1,] | | .
```